# TypeError: Sequential.add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'padding'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a model for image classification, but when I run the code, this error shows:
`TypeError: Sequential.add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'padding'` this is the model:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), 1, activation='relu', input_shape=(256,256,3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), 1, activation='relu'), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), 1, activation='relu'), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

and the error appears in the 4th line, the second time I'm adding the padding

Comment: starting from second `model.add(Cov2d ` you have wrong parenthesis, check it. You closed Conv2D parenthesis after activation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), 1, activation='relu', input_shape=(256,256,3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), 1, activation='relu'), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))
```

In the first call, because of the arrangement of parentheses, `padding` is an argument to `Conv2D()`.

But in the second call your parentheses are different, so `padding` is incorrectly given as an argument to `model.add()`.

The second call has a closing parentheses after `activation='relu'`, where the first call does not.